# A recursive fibonacci function in bash

Tags: bash, recursion, fibonacci

I was perusing the sight for some help with my code and came across a thread from about 4 months ago, however the user's final revision doesn't work when posted into bash, and produces some strange results.  Here is my version, which also produces some strange results:

```
#!/bin/bash
fib()
{
ind=$1

if (( ind <= 0 ))
 then echo 0
elif (( ind = 1 ))
 then echo 1
else
  echo $(( $(fib $((ind - 1)) ) + $(fib $((ind - 2)) ) )) 
fi
}
echo fibbonacci sequence number $1 is $(fib $1)
```

so this block of code will end up *always* outputting 1.  ./fib.sh 5 outputs 
fibbonacci sequence number 5 is 1

so I tried to write the code a little closer to what the previous asker had,

```
#!/bin/bash

fib()
 {
  ind=$1

if (( ind <= 0 ))
 then echo 1
else
  echo $(( $(fib $((ind - 1)) ) + $(fib $((ind - 2)) ) )) 
fi
 }
 echo fibbonacci sequence number $1 is $(fib $1)
```

While I don't understand the logic here, it actually starts to output fibonacci numbers,
but now I get a slightly different problem; ./fib.sh 3 outputs:
fibbonacci sequence number 3 is 5
./fib.sh 5 outputs : 
fibbonacci sequence number 5 is 13
Well we know that the 3rd fibonacci number is 1, and the 5th is 3 so what gives? The code seems to skip ahead several fibonacci numbers, and I can't figure out what is logically wrong with my code.

Comment: What bash version do you have (`bash --version`). 
Entering your code on `GNU bash, version 4.2.8(2)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)` works just fine.

Comment: OP: I didn't know the 3rd fibbonaci number was 1. Do enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when writing Fibonacci sequence logic you have to special-case the first two numbers. That's what the first user has done: special-casing 0 and 1.

You've removed one instance of special-casing and shifted everything by one index, which explains one shift. The other is easy: the code is zero-indexed. That's why everything is "off by two".

What's wrong with the original code? This line:

```
elif ((ind = 1))
```

*sets* ind to 1. Otherwise it's fine.

A simple fix to your code is to replace this line:

```
if (( ind <= 0 ))
```

with

```
if (( ind <= 2 ))
```

and off you go. That gives you the one-indexed behavior you'd expect:

```
cternus@astarael ~/foo> for i in `seq 1 10`; do ./foo.sh $i; done
fibbonacci sequence number 1 is 1
fibbonacci sequence number 2 is 1
fibbonacci sequence number 3 is 2
fibbonacci sequence number 4 is 3
fibbonacci sequence number 5 is 5
fibbonacci sequence number 6 is 8
fibbonacci sequence number 7 is 13
fibbonacci sequence number 8 is 21
fibbonacci sequence number 9 is 34
fibbonacci sequence number 10 is 55
```

Comment: so 
    elif ((ind = 1)) _sets_ ind to 1?  I don't understand, I thought that was the syntax for an else if block

when I replace if (( ind <= 0 )) with if (( ind <=2  )) I still get an "off by two" error.  I'm sorry, but I don't understand only using one special-case, I should have to special case the first and second numbers in the sequence, no?

Comment: Almost! You want `==` for an equality check, not `=`.

Comment: Alright, I managed to get the script to work correctly.  Thanks a lot Christian!

Comment: No problem! Make sure to accept the answer (click the check mark) if this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

function fib(){
    if [ $1 -le 0 ]; then
        echo 0
    elif [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
        echo 1
    else
        echo $[`fib $[$1-2]` + `fib $[$1 - 1]` ]
    fi

}

fib $1
```

Comment: Please comment your code.

Comment: It does not work for me. Have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#fibonacci sequence function
fib()
{
ind=$1

if (( ind <= 0 ))
 then echo 0
elif (( ind == 2 ))
 then echo 1
else
  echo $(( $(fib $((ind - 1)) ) + $(fib $((ind - 2)) ) )) 
fi 
}
echo fibbonacci sequence number $1 is $(fib $1)
```

So my problem was with the equality check in

```
elif (( ind = 1 ))
```

I should have used the double =, and change the 1 to a 2, so it should have been

```
elif (( ind == 2 ))
```

Ultimately my correct script should look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#fibonacci sequence function
fib()
{
ind=$1

if (( ind <= 1 ))
 then echo 0
elif (( ind == 2 ))
 then echo 1
else
  echo $(( $(fib $((ind - 1)) ) + $(fib $((ind - 2)) ) )) 
fi
 }
echo fibbonacci sequence number $1 is $(fib $1)
```

Thanks a bajillion and one to Christian Ternus for the help, I've been programming for a few years now and totally should have seen the equality check error >.<

Comment: Of course, this implementation in bash is highly suboptimal (exercise: count how many times your fib function is called)! a good exercise would be to implement memoization. It's very easy with a simple bash array and a lot of fun!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, the Korn shell executes @christianternus' script much faster than other shells:

```
$ for a in sh bash zsh ksh; do echo "shell: $a"; time for i in $(seq 1 20); do $a bin/fib.sh $i; done | md5sum; done
shell: sh
5fece53a38f2df040bfaf9632c2b7f4b  -
real    0m29.508s
user    0m3.788s
sys     0m11.785s

shell: bash
5fece53a38f2df040bfaf9632c2b7f4b  -
real    0m29.906s
user    0m3.604s
sys     0m11.235s

shell: zsh
5fece53a38f2df040bfaf9632c2b7f4b  -
real    0m29.203s
user    0m2.505s
sys     0m14.377s

shell: ksh
5fece53a38f2df040bfaf9632c2b7f4b  -
real    0m0.942s
user    0m0.843s
sys     0m0.079s
```